# global semaphores for synchronisation - counter

Tags: c, concurrency, semaphore

Below i increment a counter 1000 in two different processes and use a global semaphores for synchronisation. But iCounter doesn't give me 2000? Could someone explain to me why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define SEM_NAME "/sync"
#define NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES 2

int main ()
{
  int iCounter = 0;
  pid_t pid[NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES];
  sem_t *sSem = sem_open (SEM_NAME,O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO, 1);
  int i, iStatus;
  
  for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES; i++)
    {
      pid[i] = fork ();
      if (pid[i] < 0)
    {
      printf ("Could not create process\n");
      exit (1);
    }
      else if (pid[i] == 0)
    {
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
          sem_init(sSem, 0, 1);
          sem_wait (sSem);
          iCounter++;
          sem_post (sSem);
        }
      exit (0);
    }
    }
  for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES; i++)
    waitpid (pid[i], &iStatus, WUNTRACED);
  printf ("Value of iCounter = %d\n", iCounter);
  sem_close (sSem);
  sem_unlink (SEM_NAME);
}
```

Comment: the posted code is missing the statements: `#include <sys/types.h>` and `#include <sys/wait.h>` for the function: `waitpid()`   Your compiler should have told you about this problem.

Comment: the posted code is missing the statements: `#include <sys/types.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>` for the function: `fork()`.  Your compiler should have told you about this.

Comment: From the `sem_init()` manpage: *Initializing a semaphore that has already been initialized results in undefined behavior.* It shouldn't be used at all, actually, since you're working with a named semaphore.

Comment: Also, `iCounter` isn't shared between your processes.

Comment: running the posted code a second time (when the first execution never finished and was exited via <ctrl-c>) resulted in "sem_open failed: File exists"  suggest removing the `| O_EXCL`

Comment: after applying the above comments and running the posted code again.  the result is: "Value of iCounter = 0".   This is because the variable `iCounter` gets copied into each sub process space, so the parent process does not see any changes to that variable.  Perhaps if there were some shared memory and that memory contained the variable

Comment: this statement: `sem_t *sSem = sem_open (SEM_NAME,O_CREAT, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO, 1);` should be followed by: `if( sSem == SEM_FAILED ) { perror( "sem_open failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two big issues:

1. You're not using named semaphores correctly. `sem_init()` is only meant to be used on anonymous ones, and only once per semaphore, where you're calling it on an already initialized one many times. That's undefined behavior.
2. Your `iCounter` variable isn't shared between the processes you create.

The following reworking of your program allocates it using POSIX shared memory (And has some general cleanup):

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SEM_NAME "/sync"
#define SHM_NAME "/counter"
#define NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES 2

int main() {
  int *iCounter = MAP_FAILED;
  pid_t pid[NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES];
  int iStatus;
  int ret = 0;
  int memfd = -1;
  
  sem_t *sSem = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1);
  if (sSem == SEM_FAILED) {
    perror("sem_open");
    ret = 1;
    goto cleanup;
  }

  memfd = shm_open(SHM_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  if (memfd < 0) {
    perror("shm_open");
    ret = 1;    
    goto cleanup;
  }

  if (ftruncate(memfd, sizeof *iCounter) < 0) {
    perror("ftruncate");
    ret = 1;
    goto cleanup;
  }
  iCounter = mmap(NULL, sizeof *iCounter, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,
                  memfd, 0);
  if (iCounter == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
    ret = 1;
    goto cleanup;
  }
  close(memfd);
  *iCounter = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES; i++) {
    pid[i] = fork();
    if (pid[i] < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not create process: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      ret = 1;
      goto cleanup;
    } else if (pid[i] == 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        sem_wait(sSem);
        (*iCounter)++;
        sem_post(sSem);
      }
      sem_close(sSem);
      return 0;
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES; i++)
    waitpid(pid[i], &iStatus, WUNTRACED);

  printf("Value of iCounter = %d\n", *iCounter);

 cleanup:
  if (sSem != SEM_FAILED) {
    sem_close(sSem);
    sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);
  }
  if (memfd >= 0)
    shm_unlink(SHM_NAME);

  return ret;
}
```

Example:

```
$ gcc -g -O -Wall -Wextra example.c -lrt -lpthread
$ ./a.out
Value of iCounter = 2000
```

Comment: Since the child processes are all created by the same parent, you don't really *need* POSIX shared memory because an anonymous `mmap()` will work just as well (And an anonymous semaphore allocated in shared memory instead of using `sem_open()`), but since you're using POSIX semaphores, might as well demonstrate its sibling too.

Comment: the error handling has some logic problems:  For instance regarding: `sem_t *sSem = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1);
  if (sSem == SEM_FAILED) {
    perror("sem_open");
    ret = 1;
    goto cleanup;` .... `cleanup:
  sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);
  shm_unlink(SHM_NAME);`  This will be a problem since it is trying to unlink shared memory that has never been allocated.

Comment: @user3629249 Unlinking a non-existent object is an error that can be safely ignored.